# Create an empty file on FTP server in Java

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I need some Java way alike bash `touch`-command on FTP – create an empty file on FTP server with `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` (or another library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload an empty "in-memory file", like this:

```
InputStream bin = ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
ftpClient.storeFile("/remote/path/emptyfile", bin);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that I had written in one of my FTP utilities to create a zero byte file with name - `zeroByteFileName` and at FTP directory - `remoteDirectory`,

```
public boolean createZeroByteFile(String remoteDirectory, String zeroByteFileName) {
    FTPClient ftpClient = null;
    try (InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes())) {
        ftpClient = login(remoteDirectory);
        ftpClient.storeFile(remoteDirectory + "/" + zeroByteFileName, targetStream);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to create zero byte file - {} thru FTP (IOException) for directory - {} .",
            zeroByteFileName, remoteDirectory);
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        logOut(ftpClient);
    }
    }
```

Where I assume that you have a `logger` defined for your FTP Service ( and is an instance of `org.slf4j.Logger` ) and login & logout methods in that service as well.

Also, as far as my testing goes, this method will replace existing file with same name with new file and last modified time updated as per latest attempt.